# Why do I get a syntax error with REXML using this code?

Tags: ruby, syntax

I am using Ruby's REXML library with this code:

```
  VALID_XML_CHARS = /^(
       [\x09\x0A\x0D\x20-\x7E]            # ASCII
     | [\xC2-\xDF][\x80-\xBF]             # non-overlong 2-byte
     |  \xE0[\xA0-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]        # excluding overlongs
     | [\xE1-\xEC\xEE][\x80-\xBF]{2}      # straight 3-byte
     |  \xEF[\x80-\xBE]{2}                #
     |  \xEF\xBF[\x80-\xBD]               # excluding U+fffe and U+ffff
     |  \xED[\x80-\x9F][\x80-\xBF]        # excluding surrogates
     |  \xF0[\x90-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]{2}     # planes 1-3
     | [\xF1-\xF3][\x80-\xBF]{3}          # planes 4-15
     |  \xF4[\x80-\x8F][\x80-\xBF]{2}     # plane 16
     )*$/x;
```

I get a syntax error in the last line, and I am not sure why. Any ideas?

Comment: I tried this (1.9.2) and it works fine.

Comment: Works fine for me on 1.8.6, too.

Comment: -1 Did you try working out what was the smallest regular expression that got the same syntax error first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the place where you seem to have gotten this from ([here](http://ruby-doc.org/ruby-1.9/classes/REXML/Text.html)) ends it with /nx;